# Random wheel with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a spin wheel. I have adjusted ratio chance but I don't know how to adjust result to fit with ratio chance, particularly transform rotate. (I used transform style with turn unit)

I want the sector which is received the award always place at 90 deg. 
Thanks for your helping, please!!

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/zy8mv0fp/

HTML:

```
<div class="wheel__controller" ref="spinbutton" @click="turning">
      <h6 class="controller__label">SPIN</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="content__wrapper" ref="roulette" @transitionend="turningEnd">
      <div class="sector__wrapper">
        <div
          class="sector"
          :class="awardIdx === i && isShowResult? 'is-highlight' : ''"
          v-for="(p, i) in prizes"
          :style="`transform: rotate(${0.25 - (1/length)/2 - i*(1/length)}turn) skew(${90 - 360/length}deg)`"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="label__wrapper">
        <div
          class="label"
          v-for="(p, i) in prizes"
          :style="`transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(${-i*(1/length)}turn)`"
          :class="awardIdx === i && isShowResult ? 'is-highlight' : ''"
        >
        <img :src="p.icon" alt="Logo" style="width: 72px;transform: rotate(-85deg);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
  let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    length() {
      return this.prizes.length;
    },
    result() {
      if (this.awardIdx === -1) {
        return null;
      } else {
        var a = this.prizes[this.awardIdx].text;
        return a;
      }
    },
    resultValue() {
      if (this.awardIdx === -1) {
        return null;
      } else {
        var a = this.prizes[this.awardIdx].value;
        return a;
      }
    },
    turn() {
        this.randomRatio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-1+1)+1);
      return this.r * 50 + 5;
    },
    awardIdx() {
        if (this.randomRatio <= 60) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 60 && this.randomRatio <= 70) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 70 && this.randomRatio <= 80) {
            return 2;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 80 && this.randomRatio <= 85) {
            return 3;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 85 && this.randomRatio <= 90) {
            return 4;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 90 && this.randomRatio <= 92) {
            return 5;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 92 && this.randomRatio <= 94) {
            return 6;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 94 && this.randomRatio <= 96) {
            return 7;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 96 && this.randomRatio <= 98) {
            return 8;
        } else if (this.randomRatio > 90 && this.randomRatio <= 100) {
            return 9;
        }

    },

  },
  data() {
    return {
      prizes: [
        {
          value: "1",
          text: "Movie",
          icon: "http://pngimg.com/uploads/lamborghini/lamborghini_PNG10711.png"
        },
        {
          value: "2",
          text: "Wish",
          icon: "https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/gta-5-gun-png.png"
        },
        {
          value: "3",
          text: "Star",
          icon: "http://pngimg.com/uploads/lamborghini/lamborghini_PNG10711.png"
        },
        {
          value: "4",
          text: "Child",
          icon: "https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/gta-5-gun-png.png"
        },
        {
          value: "5",
          text: "Flight",
          icon: "http://pngimg.com/uploads/lamborghini/lamborghini_PNG10711.png"
        },
        {
          value: "6",
          text: "Bike",
          icon: "https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/gta-5-gun-png.png"
        },
        {
          value: "7",
          text: "Wifi",
          icon: "http://pngimg.com/uploads/lamborghini/lamborghini_PNG10711.png"
        },
        {
          value: "8",
          text: "Toy",
          icon: "https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/gta-5-gun-png.png"
        },
        {
          value: "9",
          text: "Award",
          icon: "http://pngimg.com/uploads/lamborghini/lamborghini_PNG10711.png"
        },
        {
          value: "10",
          text: "Dog",
          icon: "https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/gta-5-gun-png.png"
        },
      ],
      r: 0,
      randomRatio: 0,
      isShowResult: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    turning() {

        this.$refs.roulette.style.transform = `rotate(${this.turn}turn)`;
         this.$refs.roulette.classList.add("turning");
         this.$refs.spinbutton.classList.add("disabledbutton");
         this.isShowResult = false;
          this.r = Math.random();
    },
    turningEnd() {
      this.$refs.roulette.classList.remove("turning");
      this.$refs.spinbutton.classList.remove("disabledbutton");
      this.isShowResult = true;

    }
  }

})
```

Comment: To be honest: you really should make a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) when asking questions like that, so people can look at without much effort.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated my code on fiddle